# After clicking dialog doesn't show but only darkens the screen

Tags: android, dialog

After clicking dialog doesn't show but only darkens the screen. It is weird, but I don't know what happens.

This is my method which should show dialog in my fragment class. :

```
public void helloType(String id, String name) {
    AddHelloDialog dialog = AddHelloDialog.newInstance(id, name);
    dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Add hello");
}
```

And this is my AddHelloDialog class:

```
public class AddHelloDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static String HELLO_TYPE = null;
    private static String mName;
    private static String mId;

    BusManager mBusManager;

    public static AddHelloDialog newInstance(String id, String name) {
        AddHelloDialog dialog = new AddHelloDialog();
        mId = id;
        mName = name;
        return dialog;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_hello, null, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        mBusManager = BusManager.get();

        if (getArguments() != null)
            builder.setTitle(R.string.hello_dialog_title)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setView(v)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.picture_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.hello1)
    public void onHello1Click() {
        HELLO_TYPE = "1";
        addUserToNamedList();
        dismiss();
    }

    public void addUserToNamedList() {
        //API connection
    }
}
```

Why is that? Have you got any idea?

Comment: add dialog_add_hello.xml code also

Comment: dialog_add_hello.xml: http://pastebin.com/SPMgZ1zX

Answer (score 0):

You are creating custom dialog, passing viewgroup reference null during inflating layout.

```
LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_hello, null, false);
```

Hence your layout can't be attached with parent view.

Inflate your custom layout in onCreateView(...)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_hello, container);
    }
```

and get id's of view and register click lister in onViewCreated(...) method

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // for example
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);


    }
```

For detailed example https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html